# Streaming API Subscribing

Tags: streaming-api

I'm trying to create a Streaming API but I am having issues testing it, It isn't working through my code and it won't allow to me select 'Subscribe' on the work bench, I have checked all the API permissions but I have still yet to figure out the issue, I'm using 37.0 API and Chrome.  I also tried to subscribe to events on production we have, but no luck.  Any ideas?

[image: Streaming api]

Also when I inspect the elements and click subscribe I get this error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the api version to 36.0? See this: [Workbench - Unable to Subscribe to Streaming Push Topic](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kJnnIAE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems version 37.0 of the API doesn't work well with streaming. Changing the API version to 36.0 could help. See [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kJnnIAE) for more information.